# Question regarding getters, setters and components in Coldfusion 8

Tags: coldfusion, components, getter-setter

So, I'm trying to learn and utilize components to make my code better...

I  understand what getters and setters are...however, I'm not sure where to put them in respect to how my component works. My component is a faculty which has a unique id and department. I want all my information in a struct form because each faculty has a lot of information. My init method would initialize the id and the department of the specific instance and then proceed to call a query that will populate the rest of the information into a struct. I'm just not sure how to do the getters and setters for the id and department...do I just init a "blank" instance and then use a getter/ setter to actually do the input?

Also another thought/ question regarding components: 
Should my component only have methods that deal with single entities (individuals) or can I also have methods in my component that deals with the whole (like a search function for all individuals). 
...or should I separate the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a CF8 way of setting up the faculty CFC.  Notice that I didn't use the 'instance' scope 'cause when it's time to upgrade to CF9, u can remove the getters/setters and add `accessor=true` to the `cfcomponent` and you're done.  However, you may find adding an artificial 'instance' scope useful when you need to get the data out of the CFC as a struct for DAO to persist your object.

```
<cfcomponent>
  <!--- does nothing in CF8 other then for documentation purposes --->
  <cfproperty name="id">
  <cfproperty name="department">

  <!--- if you want to type your param and return type for functions in CF8, use CFML --->
  <cfscript>
    function init (id, department)
    {
      setId(id);
      setDepartment(department);

      return this;
    }

    function getId() {
        return variables.id;
    }

    function setId(id) {
         variables.id = arguments.id;
    }

    // do the same for dept
    // make use of Snippet in CFEclipse / CF Builder to gen for you

  </cfscript>

</cfcomponent>
```

> can I also have methods in my
>   component that deals with the whole
>   (like a search function for all
>   individuals). ...or should I separate
>   the two?

Usually in the CF world (inspired by the Java world), we'd separate them into `FooService` with no state, and cache your `FooService` as singleton in `Application` scope.  Then implement the Create Read Update Delete (CRUD) methods that talk to the DB in `FooDAO` (data access object) layer.  Your `FooService` would then call the CRUD methods in `FooDAO` to read (and populate) a `Foo` object for you.

Comment: Here's one of the more updated best practices for CF: http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/DevelopmentBestPractices.cfm They recommend using the `instance` scope.

Comment: so, lets say I have a form that takes in information for faculty. I want to use a function in a component to update the database with the information from the form. Do I really need to make this instanced? I feel like it would be meaningless.

Comment: For simple data that maps 1 to 1 to the DB, maybe even good old <CFINSERT> would be sufficient.  Use the right tool for the right job.